# Unable to render pixi.js sprite on canvas using Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, pixi.js

I am unable to render a Sprite on a canvas using Angular2 and pixi.js.

The code below shows how I added two Rectangles and two Sprites to a Pixi Container. When I render this Container (which contains 4 children according to the log) only the Rectangles are rendered.

I tried adding the Sprites using the fromImage() method and using a Loader, both methods don't seem to work.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(333, 333, {
      antialias: false,
      resolution: 1,
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
      backgroundColor: 0xFFFFFF
    }, false);

    this.cc.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.view);    
    this.renderer.view.style.border = "1px dashed blue";

    this.container = new PIXI.Container();

    let graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
    graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00);
    graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF0000);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 300, 200);

    let graphics2 = new PIXI.Graphics();
    graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF0000);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

    let texture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage('../../../assets/artwork/art.png');
    let sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
    sprite.x = 50;
    sprite.y = 50;
    sprite.width = 100;
    sprite.height = 100;
    sprite.visible = true;

    this.container.addChild(graphics);
    this.container.addChild(graphics2);
    this.container.addChild(sprite);
    PIXI.loader.reset();
    PIXI.loader.add('art','../../../assets/artwork/art.png').load(this.setup());
  }

  setup(): void {
    var art = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources.art.texture);
    this.container.addChild(art);
    this.renderer.render(this.container);
    console.log(this.container);
  }
```

### EDIT: Solved

With the help of user Hachi I managed to solve my problem: replacing

```
PIXI.loader.add('art','../../../assets/artwork/art.png').load(this.setup());
```

with

```
PIXI.loader.add('art', '../../../assets/artwork/art.png').load();
PIXI.loader.onLoad.add(() => {
      this.setup();
});
```

did it for me.

Comment: Rather post you solution as an answer.

Comment: This approach of calling loader will cause multiple rendering if you have an array of images to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you are calling "this.setup()" immediately, without actually waiting for it to load.

So here: 
`PIXI.loader.add('art','../../../assets/artwork/art8.png').load(this.setup());` 
.load would expect a callback funtion, but you are actually executing the function immediately on that specific line as you have parentheses there. So change it to: 
`PIXI.loader.add('art','../../../assets/artwork/art8.png').load(this.setup.bind(this));`
(I think it needs bind)

You can also use the references that the callback-function gets, as in the docs: http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.loaders.Loader.html. So loader and resources: setup(loader, resources)

Comment: You were right about the reason it wouldn't load. I managed to get it to work now. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback for easy loading as calling this.setup() will run before the loading happens. So we'll get errors like references not found or undefined.

```
PIXI.loader.add('art','../../../assets/artwork/art8.png').load(()=>this.setup());
```

While this approach may cause double rendering if you have an array of images to load.

```
PIXI.loader.add('art', '../../../assets/artwork/art.png').load();
PIXI.loader.onLoad.add(() => {
      this.setup();
});
```